# No me coge los datos en la opciones de mi peticion

Tags: nodejs, firebase, requests

Tengo una petición a una api de login, si en el form le añado los datos directamente, funciona, pero si se los añado dinámicamente, no hay forma de que funcione, parece que los parametros nunca llegan a introducirse a no ser que se añada en el codigo directamente, lo cual no me interesa. Esto esta realizado mediante Firebase Functions

```js
function autorizacion(email: string, password: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        console.log("Cosas => ", email, password);

        let emailOpt = email;
let pwdOpt = password;
        var request = require('request');
        var options = {
            'method': 'POST',
            'url': 'http://xxx.com/api/Login',
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            followRedirect: true,
            form: {
                'usuario': emailOpt,
                'pwd': pwdOpt
            }

        };
        request(options, function (error: string | undefined, response: any) {
            resolve(response.statusCode);
            if(response.statusCode == "200") resolve(true);
            else resolve(false);
        });

    })
}
```

Esta funcion la llamo desde mi function de Firebase:

```
 exports.archivosEmpresa = functions.region('europe-west2').https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

return cors(req, res, async () => {
    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

    await autorizacion(JSON.stringify(req.header('usuario')), JSON.stringify(req.header('pwd'))).then((autorizado) => {
```

)
});

Comment: ¿Porqué haces uso 2 veces del método `resolve`? Tienes: `resolve(response.statusCode);` y luego más adelante en el mismo código tienes un `resolve(true);` o un `resolve(false);` dependiendo del valor de `statusCode`. No es la forma de trabajar con Promesas. Además no veo que rechaces en ningún momento la Promesa y tampoco veo que uses `try / catch` que es lo recomendado al trabajar con Promesas. Saludos

Comment: El resolve anterior es un fallo. Quisiera saber como rechazar la promesa y como usar en este caso el try/catch

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea escribir un función que realice un proceso de llamada a una API mediante [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) en NodeJS. (Por cierto, la librería `request` está marcada como obsoleta desde Febrero 2020, ver este [*post* de Github](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142)).

Sin embargo la forma en que se implementa dicha función no es correcta, produciendo un resultado no esperado o incluso ambiguo.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Vamos a partir del hecho de refactorizar la función actual y luego veremos de evitar el uso de la librería `request` para realizar el trabajo, optando por alguna otra que nos permita realizar la tarea.

Actualmente tu función recibe dos parámetros de tipo `string`:

```
function autorizacion(email: string, password: string) { ... }
```

Luego, tu función pretende devolver una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) haciendo:

```
return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => { ... } );
```

A partir de aquí, tu función llamada `autorizacion` es una Promesa, por lo tanto para trabajar con ella tenemos al menos dos opciones:

1. Usar los método `then()` y `catch()` que implementan todas las Promesas.
2. Usar la sentencia `await` dentro de un entorno o función [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona). Para ello debemos envolver el código en un bloque `try / catch`, o bien capturar la posible execpción usando `async` y el método `catch()` ya que toda función tipo `async` devuelve una Promesa.

Por otro lado, si trabajas con [NodeJS 6.4.0 o superior](https://node.green/#ES2015-bindings), te sugiero que evites usar `var` para declarar tus variables. Utiliza `let` y `const`.

Volviendo a tu problema, ¿qué deseas realmente lograr con la función `autorizacion`?, es decir, ¿qué debe hacer esta función? o mejor ¿qué debe devolver esta función?.

Viendo o analizando esta parte del código:

```js
request(options, function (error: string | undefined, response: any) {
  resolve(response.statusCode);
  if(response.statusCode == "200") resolve(true);
  else resolve(false);
});
```

Se ve que intentas devolver un valor booleano, dependiendo del código de estado de la respuesta recibida por el método `request`.

Partiendo de esto vamos a reescribir la función `autorizacion` para que podamos usarla correctamente en nuestra aplicación.

**Usando `then` y `catch`**

Usaremos los métodos `then` y `catch` que nos provee nuestra Promesa de esta forma no necesitamos usar un entorno `async`, por ejemplo:

```js
// importación de la librería request
const request = require('request');

// declaración de la función
function autorizacion(email: string, password: string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let emailOpt = email;
    let pwdOpt = password;
    const options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'url': 'http://xxx.com/api/Login',
      'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      followRedirect: true,
      form: {
        'usuario': emailOpt,
        'pwd': pwdOpt
      }
    };

    request(options, function (error: any, response: any) {
      // aqui manejamos el error en caso que la solicitud lance uno
      if(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        return reject(error);
      }
      // si no hay error, verificamos el código de estado de la solicitud
      if(response.statusCode === 200) return resolve(true); // devolvemos true
      resolve(false); // devolvemos false. La solicitud no tiene código 200
    }); // fin de request
  }); // fin de new Promise
} // fin de autorizacion
```

Notemos que tanto en el manejo del error como en el manejo del código de respuesta se usa una sentencia `return`. Esto es para indicar que la función finaliza allí y no debe seguir ejecutando el código que le sigue. También es importante notar que he introducido el operador de comparación estricta en: `response.statusCode === 200` y he cambiado el valor del segundo operando por un valor numérico. Esto debido a que los [códigos de estado](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_statuscode) del [Objeto Response](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) de NodeJS, son de tipo numérico.

También he cambiado el tipo de la variable `error` esperado por la función `callback` que pasas al método `request`, ya que usualmente se recibe un objeto de [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Error) o un valor [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/null), pero nunca un `string`.

Ahora podemos usar nuestra función de autorización de la siguiente manera:

```js
exports.archivosEmpresa = functions
.region('europe-west2')
.https
.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return cors(req, res, () => {
    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    autorizacion(
      JSON.stringify(req.header('usuario')),
      JSON.stringify(req.header('pwd'))
    )
    .then(autorizado => {
      if(autorizado) {
        // acciones en caso de que autorizado es true
        // no olvidar poner un return aquí
      }
      // acciones en caso que autorizado es false
    })
    .catch(e => {
      // acciones en caso de error
    }); // fin de autorizacion
  }); // fin de cors
}); // fin de onRequest
```

De esta forma cubrimos el resultado de nuestra Promesa, ya sea esta resuelta o rechazada.

**Usando `try / catch` en un entorno `async` con `await`.

Otra forma de usar nuestra función `autorizacion` es usando la sentencia `await` dentro de un entorno `async`. Para ello debemos implementar el código en un bloque `try / catch`. Por ejemplo:

```js
exports.archivosEmpresa = functions
.region('europe-west2')
.https
.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return cors(req, res, async () => { // <- aquí declaramos un entorno async
    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    try {
      let autorizado = await autorizacion( // <- usamos await
        JSON.stringify(req.header('usuario')),
        JSON.stringify(req.header('pwd'))
      );
      // ahora la variable autorizado es true o false
      if(autorizado) {
        // acciones en caso de que autorizado es true
        // no olvidar poner un return aquí
      }
      // acciones en caso que autorizado es false
      // ...
    }
    catch(e) {
      // acciones en caso de error
    }
  }); // fin de cors
}); // fin de onRequest
```

De esta forma estaremos usando la sentencia `await` correctamente para esperar el resultado de nuestra Promesa y el bloque `catch` manejará un posible error (cuando la Promesa es rechazada).

Si no deseamos usar un bloque `try / catch` podemos hacer uso de `await` en conjunto con `async`. Por ejemplo:

```js
exports.archivosEmpresa = functions
.region('europe-west2')
.https
.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return cors(req, res, async () => { // <- aquí declaramos un entorno async
    const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    let autorizado = await autorizacion( // <- usamos await
      JSON.stringify(req.header('usuario')),
      JSON.stringify(req.header('pwd'))
    );
    // ahora la variable autorizado es true o false
    if(autorizado) {
      // acciones en caso de que autorizado es true
      // no olvidar poner un return aquí
    }
    // acciones en caso que autorizado es false
    // ...
  }) // fin del entorno async (devuelve una Promesa, podemos capturar excepciones)
  .catch(e => {
    // manejamos el posible error
    // ...
  }); // fin de cors
}); // fin de onRequest
```

---

Como dije en un principio, la librería `request` está obsoleta, por lo tanto debemos buscar alguna alternativa, entre las cuales puedo mencionar:

- [`got`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).
- [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).
- [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).
- [`superagent`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent).

**Usando `axios`**

Vamos a ver como se simplifica el código de nuestra función, ya que `axios` devuelve ya directamente una Promesa.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// importamos la librería
const axios = require('axios').default;

// declaración de la función
function autorizacion (email: string, password: string) {
  let emailOpt = email;
  let pwdOpt = password;
  const config = {
    'method': 'post',
    'url': 'http://xxx.com/api/Login',
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    maxRedirects: 5, // default
    data: {
      'usuario': emailOpt,
      'pwd': pwdOpt
    }
  };
  return axios(config)
  .then(response: any => {
    if(response.status === 200) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  })
  .catch(error: any => {
    // aquí manejamos el error en caso que la solicitud lance uno
    throw error;
  });
} // fin de autorizacion
```

Nuestra función `autorizacion` sigue devolviendo una Promesa:

```
return axios(config)
```

Por lo cual, aplican las mismas prerrogativas para el manejo de la misma en el ámbito donde vayamos a usarla.

Para mayor información de esta librería, debes leer la [documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api).

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.